# How to fix orientation of Photo Taken from phone camera and bind it to image view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am facing some issues when I am trying to bind photo taken from camera through my application and binding it to the image view and binding image from gallery.
I use Micromax Phone for testing our application, it works fine and binds the image as it is from that phone, but when we change our phone for example Samsung the original orientation is different than the hardware orientation so what is happening is that it is binding as per the orientation set by the hardware.
I tried to correct the orientation but was not working at all.
Can any one please try to solve my problem......

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.IO;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Content.PM;
using MyApplication.Droid;
using Android.Media;

namespace MyApplication.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "CameraActivity")]
    public class CameraActivity : Activity
    {
        File _file;
        File _dir;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView _imageView, _imageView1;
       int PickImageId = 1;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Camera);
            if (IsThereAnAppToTakePictures())
            {
                CreateDirectoryForPictures();

                Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.TakePik);
                _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView2);
                _imageView1= FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
                button.Click += TakeAPicture;
            }
            Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Galary);
            button1.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetType("image/*");
                intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);

            };

            // Create your application here

        }
        private void CreateDirectoryForPictures()
        {
            _dir = new File(
                Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "MRohit Task");
            if (!_dir.Exists())
            {
                _dir.Mkdirs();
            }
        }
        private bool IsThereAnAppToTakePictures()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            IList<ResolveInfo> availableActivities =
                PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
            return availableActivities != null && availableActivities.Count > 0;
        }
        private void TakeAPicture(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            _file = new File(_dir, String.Format("MRohit_Task_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
            intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file));
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                _imageView1.SetImageURI(uri);
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                // Make it available in the gallery

                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                Android.Net.Uri contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(_file);
                mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
                SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                //   string str_file_path = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(_file.Path.ToString()).ToString();
                // Display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display.
                // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory
                // and cause the application to crash.

                int height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
                int width = _imageView.Height;
                bitmap = _file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);
                ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(_file.Path);
                int orientation = ei.GetAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TagOrientation,
                                                     (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Undefined);

                switch (orientation)
                {

                    case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate90:
                        rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                        break;

                    case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate180:
                        rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                        break;

                    case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate270:
                        rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                        break;

                    case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Normal:

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if (bitmap != null)
                {
                    _imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    bitmap = null;
                }
                // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

            public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle)
        {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.PostRotate(angle);
            return Bitmap.CreateBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.Width, source.Height,
                                       matrix, true);
        }
    }
    //To crop the image size
    public static class BitmapHelpers
    {
        public static Bitmap LoadAndResizeBitmap(this string fileName, int width, int height)
        {

            ////// First we get the the dimensions of the file on disk
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
            BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);


            ////// Next we calculate the ratio that we need to resize the image by
            ////// in order to fit the requested dimensions.
            int outHeight = options.OutHeight;
            int outWidth = options.OutWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (outHeight > height || outWidth > width)
            {
                inSampleSize = outWidth > outHeight
                                   ? outHeight / height
                                   : outWidth / width;
            }

           // Now we will load the image and have BitmapFactory resize it for us.
           options.InSampleSize = inSampleSize;
           options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
           Bitmap resizedBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);

            return resizedBitmap;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can any one please answer this #grace-feng-msft  or #himanshu-dwivedi